# Is there a way to add series to a chart without knowing ahead of time how many series will be in it?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, shieldui

I tried below code by adding foreach loop, it looked like it's not allowed to add code inside the Html.ShieldChart, anybody can help? Thanks in advance.

```
@(Html.ShieldChart()
.Name("chart1")
.Theme("abc")
...
foreach (PercentileRank p in prank)
{
 .DataSeries(d => d.Line().Data(p.Ranks).CollectionAlias(p.Division))
}
...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a syntax error and hence does not work.

What you can do is in your Razor view, create a Chart helper with code similar to [this Grid helper](http://demos.shieldui.com/mvc/grid-virtualization/performance-1mil-rows):

```
@{
    var grid = Html.ShieldGrid()
        .DataSourceExpression(@<text>window.gridSource</text>)
        .Height(400)
        .ScrollingConfiguration(scrolling => scrolling.Virtual(true));

    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        grid.Columns(col => col.Field("col" + i).Width(140));
    }
}
```

Then in you can render the helper in your view by simply adding:

```
@grid
```